# GTK+ Vte.Terminal().fork_command_full removed?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, gtk3, pty

I noticed this last week. All my code on ubuntu 15.04 was working fine using

> Vte.Terminal().fork_command_full

Also [this documentation site](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Vte-2.91/classes/Terminal.html#Vte.Terminal) was showing this function as well, but does not now. Has this function been removed? If so, then what is the next simplest alternative to get a virtual terminal widget working.
As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155739/253749) suggests the use of the above command, what is the next best way to get this widget up and running?

> NOTE: I am using python3 for this code

Comment: ***Finally*** someone notices...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: This answer is now [deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-spawn-sync). Please see the [answer by @Maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322616/3488231) instead.

---

The function call for the C API has been renamed from

```
vte_terminal_fork_command_full ()
```

to

```
vte_terminal_spawn_sync ()
```

since VTE 0.38.

As a result, the corresponding Python function has been renamed from `fork_command_full()` to `spawn_sync()`.

Answer (score 1):

The function has been renamed from

```
vte_terminal_spawn_sync()
```

to

```
vte_terminal_spawn_async()
```

Since version VTE 0.48